# How to Compare 2 different json response from 2 different API in soapui?

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

Assume I am creating users,and I can fetch these users details from 2 different repository (Local server, central hub).

So When I do a GET method for this API, I will receive set of values,(Say this GET method is from local server) and when I do another GET (say this GET method is from central hub).

My requirement is to compare whether these two different API response are same or not? How to achieve this?
Sample response:

```
[
      {
      "name": "ABCD",
      "user": "TEMP_USER",
      "description": null,
      "createdtime": "2017-11-06 11:11:18",
      "groupname": "XYZ",
      "tempId": 101998,
   },
{
      "name": "EFGH",
      "user": "TEMP_USER",
      "description": null,
      "createdtime": "2017-11-05 11:11:18",
      "groupname": "XYZ",
      "tempId": 101999,
   }
]
```

Comment: Basavaraj, where is the second response which you wanted to compare the above one?

Comment: Expected is, Second response also should be the same as first one. So you can consider both as same and then compare.

Answer (score 2):

Below, I'm assuming that `resp1Str` and `resp2Str` both contain the JSON from the original post.

Rather than post a wall of code, we can build up a solution (also listed [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_groovy/tree/master/egg_30_stack_overflow_47140200)). First, consider parsing the JSON into a list of maps, and sort the lists by `name`:

```
def resp1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(respStr1)
def resp2 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(respStr2)

resp1.sort{a,b -> a.name <=> b.name}
resp2.sort{a,b -> a.name <=> b.name}

assert compareUsers(resp1, resp2)
```

Now, we need to implement `compareUsers`. It converts each map into a `UserInfo` object that can be compared via `compareUser` (not listed here):

```
def compareUsers = { resp1, resp2 ->
    def result = true

    if (resp1.size() == resp2.size()) {
        // assume lists are sorted
        [resp1, resp2].transpose().each {
            def userInfo1 = buildUserInfo(it[0])
            def userInfo2 = buildUserInfo(it[1])
            if (result) {
                result = compareUser(userInfo1, userInfo2)
            }
        }
    } else {
        result = false
    }

    result
}
```

The implementation of `compareUser` simply compares `keys` and `values` (we will see that `keys` are sorted and `values` are sorted by key):

```
def compareUser = { userInfo1, userInfo2 ->
    (userInfo1.keys == userInfo2.keys) && (userInfo1.values == userInfo2.values)
}
```

Finally, we need to see how to convert a map into the `UserInfo`, which uses Groovy's `Expando` feature:

```
def buildSortedList = { items ->
    def list = []
    list.addAll(items)
    Collections.sort(list)
    list
}

def buildUserInfo = { user ->
    def result = new Expando()
    result.keys = buildSortedList(user.keySet())
    result.values = []
    result.keys.each { key -> result.values << user[key] }
    result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Grab(group='org.skyscreamer', module='jsonassert', version='1.5.0', scope='test')

import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert;

def a='''[{
      "name": "ABCD",
      "user": "TEMP_USER",
      "description": null,
      "createdtime": "2017-11-06 11:11:18",
      "groupname": "XYZ",
      "tempId": 101998
}]'''
def b='''[{
      "name": "ABCD",
      "user": "TEMP_USER",
      "description": null,
      "createdtime": "2017-11-06 11:11:18",
      "groupname": "XYZ",
      "tempId": 1019981
}]'''

JSONAssert.assertEquals(a,b,false)
```

Comment: But how to define a and b, because value a can be anything. but definetly value of b should be same as a. So when we dont know a how to pick from response then compare it with the responce of b ?

Comment: what do you mean? you said: `I can fetch these users details from 2 different repository`. `a` and `b` - the json response from your two services. to be able to run code snippet i put them as constants.

Comment: Yes, I can fetch these user details. But what i am trying to tell is value can be dynamic. eg. today if name is ABCD tommorow it can be XYZ. So in such case i cant define a. But oly requirment is a and b should be same.

Comment: yes, do it dynamic and the `JSONAssert.assertEquals(a,b,false)` will compare if `a` and `b` are the same...